# How to open AlertDialog by clicking on RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I have a little problem. I cant open `AlertDialog` by clicking on `RecyclerView` item.. Here is my `AlertDialog` code:

```
public class LoginDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);
        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Login")
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Now I want to display it by clicking on `RecyclerView` item. Here is the Adapter code:

```
public class UserAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
    private List<UserModel> list;
    Context context;

    public UserAdapter(List<UserModel>list, Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        UserModel user = list.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(user.name + " " + user.surname);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog();
               loginDialog.show()
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textName;

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        }
    } 
}
```

Sadly, I cannot do nothing with `loginDialog.show()`. I can't resolve `getSupportFragmentManager` or `getFragmentManager`. The only option is to create new function called `show` in `LoginDialog` class. But then I get NPE all the time..

Comment: You need `Activity's` Context to get `SupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: pass reference of supportFragmentManger to your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make things better you need to understand responsibility of Adapter and Activity. Adapter should bind data to views and that's it. If you want to show Dialog on item click it's better to do it like:

```
public UserAdapter(List<UserModel>list, Context context, View.OnClickListener itemClickListener){
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

......
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false), itemClickListener);
}
......
public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textName;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView, View.OnClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        textName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
} 
....
```

In Your fragment/activity:

```
adapter = new UserAdapter(List<UserModel>list, Context context, new View.OnClickListener(){
   new LoginDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, LoginDialog.TAG)
})
```

Comment: Well, the thing is that i use `RecyclerViewer` in my `MainActivity` , the activity where `RecyclerView` `items` are displayed, and where i also want to display `AlertDialog`, so i shold use the last two lines of your code in my `MainActivity` class, yes?

Comment: @BartSumps yes, the idea is to inject click listener into adapter and set it to the particular view, that should trigger the event. In Kotlin this role can play lambda ()->Unit

Comment: thank you for good explanation, it works perfectly, also thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

You already have `Context` in `Adapter` . So you can directly use it .

```
LoginDialog dialogFragment = new LoginDialog ();
 dialogFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Fragment");
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method "show(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity)"

Comment: allright it's working, cant vote for your answer because i cant vote with my points :/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you modify your `LoginDialog` like the following.

```
public class LoginDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private Context context;

    public LoginDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((AppCompatActivity)context)).getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);
        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Login")
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

The idea is to create a constructor and pass the context to your `LoginDialog` each time you are creating it from your adapter. Then while creating the `Dialog` you need to pass the context every time.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog(context);
       loginDialog.show()
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.